# How to map original column values with their one-hot encoded values?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I've used the following code to one-hot encode some categorical variables in my dataframe:

```
X = Dataframe[feature_cols] # Features
X_encoded = pd.get_dummies(data=X)
```

Is there a way to print the original values from the Dataframe alongside their one-hot encoded values to map what the one-hot encoded values represent? So for example, if I had a column "Gender" in my original dataframe, is there a way I can print the compared values from the 'X_encoded' dataframe to show for example:

- Female (from X) = 0 (in X_encoded)
- Male (from X) = 1 (in X_encoded)

Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: With two classes, it's just `np.array(['Female','Male'])[X_encoded[:,0]]`.

Comment: For general case with more than 2 classes, use `np.argmax(X_encoded, axis=1)` instead of `X_encoded[:,0]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you for your comment, so does that mean I don't need to specify which column of the dataframe to look at?